# Ruby calling method in quick_sort gives wrong output

Tags: ruby, quicksort

I am doing a quick sort in ruby and using quick_sort I am grabbing the last 3 elements of the array and multiplying it to get the value.

My quick sort works fine but only thing is when I call the my other method `max_product_three` in `quick_search` the `sorted_array` I pass into the method is only showing up as two random numbers like `[-3,-2]`. If I take out my method from quick_search it gives the correct output. What is happening that when I put my method the sorted array is wrong which is causing my `max_product_three` not to work.

quick_search.rb

```
def quick_search(array)
  return array if array.length <= 1
  len = array.length - 1
  left = []
  right = []
  pivot = array.sample
  array.delete_at(array.index(pivot))

  array.each do |num|
    if num < pivot
      left << num
    else
      right << num
    end
  end
    sorted = []
    sorted << quick_search(left)
    sorted << pivot
    sorted << quick_search(right)
    sorted_array = sorted.flatten
    p sorted_array
    max_product_three(sorted_array)
end
```

max_product_three.rb

```
def max_product_three(sorted_array)
  len = sorted_array.length - 1
  take_3 = len - 3
  mulitple = sorted_array.drop(take_3)
  p mulitple.inject(:*)
end
```

I am using this array as reference `[-3,1,2,-2,5,6]`

Comment: Try using `max_product_three` somewhere other than in the middle of your recursive sort.

Comment: @red_menace thanks! yeah I made it into a class and did it that way and worked by moving out where I called it. But, was it messing because it was calling that method during recursion as well?

Comment: Yep, the `max_product_three` method is trying to do its thing with the array while you are still sorting it.

Comment: `[-3,1,2,-2,5,6].max(3).inject(:*)`

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're writing this to learn how quick-sort works? Because ruby's got a `#sort` method right there...

There are few things here. Is your intention to do two things: first, sort the array; second, multiply the three largest values in the sorted array? Because that's not what your code currently does. You call your `max_product_three` method from within your sort, which means it'll be called every time `quick_sort` is called.

Worse, it's the last line in the method. That means the result of calling `max_product_three` is what's returned each time you iterate, not the sorted array! So, for each sub-sort, what you get back is a single number instead of the sorted array.

Also, your `max_product_three` method multiplies the last *4* values, not the last 3 values. (You subtract 1 from its length and then subtract 3 from it, so you're dropping length - 4 values, leaving 4 values to multiply.)

You don't need to do `p sorted_array` at the end of your quick_search method (presumably, should be `quick_sort`!) but can just have `sorted_array` to return the array.

And, a smaller thing, your initial guard clause would be a bit better (and more ruby-ish) by not using an explicit operator, for example:

```rb
return array unless array.length.positive?
```

That's quite a lot, and I may have misinterpreted what you're trying to do here so let me know if I have!